# Clear the least significant set bit

Tags: haskell, bit-manipulation

I'd like to clear the least significant set bit of an arbitrary Bits type. The problem is, that I do not necessarily have the `Num` instance, so `x.&.(x-1)` is not an option. The only function I could think of is this:

```
clearLsb x = x `clearBit` countTrailingZeros x
```

I benchmarked it against the `x&(x-1)` version, and it is 1.5 slower on `Word32` and `Word64` regardless of the level of optimization. I would appreciate if anyone knows some clever hack to do it.

Comment: You can emulate arithmetic with logic operations, but doubt it's faster.

Comment: I can't avoid wondering why you can't use the `Num` subtraction, and the formula you posted.

Comment: @chi because I might have a type like data Mask = Mask Word Word ..., for which it would be quite natural to make a Bits instance, but Num is much more involved.

Answer (score 3):

You may overload the function to *pick* the more efficient implementation *at the type level*, when it is available. This requires adding a type class, but even with [`countTrailingZeros`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Bits.html#v:countTrailingZeros) implementation you already have to impose *some* type-class constraint to your function (namely [`FiniteBits`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Bits.html#t:FiniteBits)) <sup>(1)</sup>.

In particular, with some language extensions, all `Num` types can set to use `a .&. (a - 1)` equation<sup>(2)</sup>:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, UndecidableInstances #-}

import Data.Bits (Bits, (.&.))

class LSB a where
    clear :: a -> a

instance (Bits a, Num a) => LSB a where
    clear a = a .&. (a - 1)  -- more efficient implementation

newtype Foo = ...  -- some type not instance of Num

instance LSB Foo where
    clear a = ... -- some other approach
```

---

<sub>1. do also note that with `countTrailingZeros` you are ruling out `Integer` type, that is `countTrailingZeros (16 :: Integer)` will *not* type check, since it is not an instance of `FiniteBits`.

2. Though would be better to write explicit instances than use those language extensions</sub>

Comment: `FiniteBits` was terribly named, IMO. It should have been named `FixedBits` or something. `FiniteBits` should have admitted types each of whose values has finitely many bits.

Comment: The typeclass solution looks best for the purpose. But doesn't it kind of violate the philosophy behind haskell typeclasses? It adds no new abstraction, no interesting algebraic laws.. Though it would have been a nice addition to the Bits package (I mean the function, not the typeclass).

Comment: @lanskey typeclasses are the mechanism that haskell uses to provide *ad hoc polymorphism*. Usually this involves having an abstraction but there are instances where you just want the ad hoc polymorphism, i.e. being able to implement some method for various types and write generic code that does the right thing. This seems one of those cases.